# Can I choose to use Axis2 rather than CXF?

Tags: web-services, cxf, apache-axis

I have a WSDL file from a service provider. The sample code from the service provider uses CXF. Could there be anything about their service that requires CXF, or should I be able to use Axis2 if I prefer?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Yes you can !  If a wsdl contract is provide you don't care of the technologies use to implements it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I will advise to use Spring WS, since CFX is inclined towards spring.